# How to extract methods that call MLKit process(), outside of CameraX analyze()?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax, google-mlkit

For code clarity and better reusability I'd like to have something like this

```
class MyAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
    private val faceDetector = FaceDetection.getClient()

    @androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        val mediaImage = imageProxy.image ?: return
        val image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

        if (getFace(image) != null) {
            // do stuff
        }

        imageProxy.close()
    }

    private fun getFace(image: InputImage): Face? {
        var face: Face? = null

        faceDetector.process(image).addOnSuccessListener { faces ->
            face = faces.firstOrNull()
        }

        return face
    }   
}
```

but when I run the app it always raises this exception

```
E/NativeFaceDetectorV2Imp: Native face detection v2 failed
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.nio.ByteBuffer.isDirect()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.face.NativeFaceDetectorV2Impl.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal@@16.1.0:96)
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.face.internal.client.zzb.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@@20.1.3:34)
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector.detect(com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@@20.1.3:27)
        at com.google.mlkit.vision.face.internal.zzg.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection@@16.1.2:23)
        at com.google.mlkit.vision.face.internal.zzg.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection@@16.1.2:3)
        at com.google.mlkit.vision.face.internal.zzg.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection@@16.1.2)
        at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.MobileVisionBase.zza(com.google.mlkit:vision-common@@16.2.0)
        at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.zzc.call(com.google.mlkit:vision-common@@16.2.0)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.ModelResource.zza(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.0)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzn.run(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.0)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzp.run(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.0:2)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zze(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.0:4)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzc(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.0)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzj.run(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.0)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzd(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.0)
        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzk.run(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

**Edit:** I've found the reason for the exception and fixed it (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814276/9212745) below), but there's still something off with the code because I still can't get the outcome I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the culprit. I pasted the first code example wrong, with `imageProxy.close()` after the block called for `addOnSuccessListener { }`, but in reality it was always inside it. The current situation is

```
class MyAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
    private val faceDetector = FaceDetection.getClient()

    @androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        val mediaImage = imageProxy.image ?: return
        val image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

        if (getFace(image, imageProxy) != null) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    private fun getFace(image: InputImage, imageProxy: ImageProxy): Face? {
        var face: Face? = null

        /* old code
         *
         * faceDetector.process(image).addOnSuccessListener { faces ->
         *     face = faces.firstOrNull()
         *     imageProxy.close()
         * }
         */

        // solution code
        runBlocking {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val faces = Tasks.await(faceDetector.process(image))

                face = faces.firstOrNull()
                imageProxy.close()
            }
        }

        return face
    }   
}
```

Now at least it doesn't raise an exception anymore and if I log the face in the listener block it's fine, but the code in `if (getFace(image, imageProxy) != null)` doesn't run. I think it's because `faceDetector.process()` hasn't finished yet, so `getFace()` returns immediately `face` which is still `null` from initialization and when the listener gets triggered it's too late. Any suggestion?

**Edit:** found the culprit again. It was exactly like I imagined and all I needed to do was to find another way to wait for `faceDetector.process()` to complete. Since it returns a `Task<T>`, after fumbling for a while I discovered that I could just use `Tasks.await()` and after wrapping it in a nice coroutine everything seems to be good. I've fixed the code in this answer to reflect my latest changes.

Comment: You will need to call faceDetector.process(image).addOnSuccessListener { faces ->
            face = faces.firstOrNull()
            imageProxy.close()
        }
directly in the analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {...} method. You should check whether the face is null or not in the onSuccessListener

Comment: @ChenxiSong I solved it, look at the edit in the answer.